# React state is not updating in the first time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a image upload component where user can upload one or multiple images at a time. When the user upload an image I always try to update the state using useState(). But the state is not updating in the very first time. How can I update the below code to make this work.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState([]);

  const uploadImages = (event) => {
    console.log('NewFile=>', event.target.files);

    setFile([...file, ...event.target.files]);
    console.log('UpdatedFiles=>', file);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        multiple
        type="file"
        name="photo"
        id="photo"
        accept="image/*"
        capture="environment"
        onChange={(event) => uploadImages(event)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ujcbjh?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use useState with something which is not a primitive type, you should be wary.

These two pages in reacts documentation will give you some clarification:

- https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state
- https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state

In short, react uses `Object.is` to determine if the state changed between calls to `setState`. For objects and arrays, this may return true, even if the content of it changes.